# Parsing XML, skip certain tags

Tags: java, xml

I am following **mkyong's** great [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) on how to parse xml in Java, but I have a situation where I need to read certain tags but only within an area. e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
    <changes>
        <staff id="2001">
            <firstname>low</firstname>
            <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
            <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
            <old_salary>175000</salary>
            <new_salary>200000</salary>
        </staff>
    </changes>
</company>
```

In the tutorial it uses `NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");` but this retrieves all of the staff, including the one under `<changes>`. How can I disregard all `<staff>` tags under `<changes>`?

Thanks

Comment: Look at using XPATH queries.

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM parser is not the best for your need.
Using [XPath queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) should be better. ([API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html))

For exemple :

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 
    Document doc = db.parse(new File("test.xml"));

    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/company/staff";

    //read a nodelist using xpath
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying the items that you are intending to save you can attempt to catch it if it is under changes and then ignore it. ex

```
 if(company.changes != null)
{
//skip saving this node

}
```